# How can I get terraform stdout to stream in a github action?

Tags: terraform, continuous-integration, github-actions, stdout

When I run terraform commands from my local machine the stdout and stderr of the process streams into my terminal as it runs.

When I run the exact same commands against the exact same terraform template in a Github Action, the stdout and stderr will not be displayed until the very end of the command where it will dump all of it suddenly.

[image: example]

This is very frustrating as it can take a very long time to run sometimes and we have a particular issue where it appears that one of the steps can actually get hung but I can't tell which since the output is not streaming, and if you cancel the github action, github will eat all subsequent output, so there is no way to see what is hanging.

How can I get terraform to stream all of its output like it does locally while running inside of a github action?

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: Try `stdbuf -o0 -e0 terraform apply ...` and see if that works. The shell being used is Bash. Are you using an Ubuntu runner? Your local is also the same?

Comment: It turns out that there is a bug in the setup terraform action right now, you can set `wrapper_enabled: false` to fix it. Here is details on the issue https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform/issues/395

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the test I just completed:

```
name: 'Terraform'

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
  pull_request:

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: 'Terraform'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0

    - name: Setup Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1

    - name: Terraform Version
      run: terraform version -json

    - name: Terraform Init
      run: |
        cd TerraForm/time_sleep/
        terraform init

    - name: Terraform Apply
      run: |
        cd TerraForm/time_sleep/
        terraform apply -auto-approve
```

in the terraform side I'm mostly doing time_sleep:

```hcl
resource "time_sleep" "wait" {
  count           = 15
  create_duration = "${count.index + 1}s"
}
```

The full code is here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/tree/master/TerraForm/time_sleep

We can see no issues:
[image]

Comment: crazy... can you remove the defaults shell bash? I wonder if its the difference with sh vs bash?

If not then I will say we are not using the ubuntu-latest image, we have an on-prem runner which is very similar but a little different. Is it possibly something that could differ on the runner itself?

Comment: I've changed my action to be nodejs20 based, and have it inherit the stdout / stderr and it is still doing the same thing. Are there any known env vars to control this behavior?

Comment: @justin.m.chase I'm no expert on this topic ... but you do have a working sample now, work up from that see where your stuff bricks

Comment: I'm wondering if the base ubuntu runner has TF_LOG env var set by default and mine doesn't? Are you able to export your TF_LOG env var? I'm going to try to set that explicitly and see if its somehow defaulting to nothing on linux. On my local machine its not set but the output streaming works as expected.

Comment: So it turns out the difference was that you're using @v1 of setup-terraform while I am using v3. There is a "wrapper" which is currently bugged that you can disable and the streaming works again as expected. Details on the bug can be found here: https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform/issues/395